# how to add a random id feature on each new record insert in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, random, insert, record

I have a table which has to do with posts

**schema:**

```
id | post_id | user_id | title | content
```

right now all columns are set and work as intended but now i want to add a unique ID in the post_id column like **7384756291** in each new record insert into the database

how can i add this feature? i guess i can easily create a random ID but the problem is how to make sure its unique from the others before the record is inserted, otherwise create new and try again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep trying until it doesn't exist:

```
post_id = rand(10000000000)

while Model.exists?(:post_id => post_id)
  post_id = rand(10000000000)
end

Model.create(:post_id => post_id, ...)
```